# How to consume SharePoint 2013 web service without adding reference in Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, web-services, soap

Is there any other way to consume a SharePoint 2013 web service other than adding its service reference in visual studio?

What if I want to do this at runtime? Is there an example available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using posting SOAP messages to the web service using `HttpClient` object (MSDN for [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)). You can look here in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336414/httpclient-soap-c. It shows how to make a SOAP web service call using C#.

On the other hand if your're using SharePoint 2013 you should know, that SOAP Web Services is now [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx#DeprecatedAPIs). You should be using REST Web Services (or maybe SharePoint CSOM) that is much more simple to consume from C# or JavaScript, than making huge SOAP request.